# For next loop multiplying numbers

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to create a calculator where a user inputs a number (1-20) and it gives the user the option to get the sum or product from 1 to the number they entered. ie the sum of 5 would be 15 while the product would be 120. I am using select case and a for next loop. I have managed to get the sum portion of the calculator working correctly and thought I could use the same principle for the product portion but I am having no such luck. Any help or a gentle nudge in the right direction would greatly appreciated.
Cheers.

Code:

```
    Dim intsum As Integer
    Dim intnum As Integer
    Dim intproduct As Integer

    If IsNumeric(txtinput.Text) Then
        intnum = CInt(txtinput.Text)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value", "Input error")
        txtinput.Clear()
        txtinput.Focus()

    End If

    If intnum >= 1 AndAlso intnum <= 20 Then

        Select Case True

            Case btnproduct.Checked
                For P = 1 To intnum Step 1
                    intproduct = intproduct * P

                Next


            Case btnsum.Checked
                For S = 1 To intnum Step 1
                    intsum = intsum + S
                Next




        End Select
```

Comment: I think you need to initialize `initproduct` to 1.

Comment: You need to initialise intproduct before the loop, it'll be constantly zero with the code above.

Comment: You might want to reconsider the range of values you support. `20!` = `2.432902e+18` which won't fit in an `Integer`

Comment: For broader nudges, you might want to look up [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28VS.90%29.aspx) (but beware that the second parameter is a count, not the end value), [`Enumerable.Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate(v=vs.90).aspx) and [Lambdas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise intproduct to = 1 as at the moment you are multiplying your value by 0 so it will always show the final result as 0.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check the value of `intnum` if the value is not numeric.

```
Dim intsum As Integer
Dim intnum As Integer
Dim intproduct As Integer

If IsNumeric(txtinput.Text) Then
    intnum = CInt(txtinput.Text)

    If intnum >= 1 AndAlso intnum <= 20 Then

        Select Case True

        Case btnproduct.Checked
            For P = 1 To intnum Step 1
                intproduct = intproduct * P

            Next


        Case btnsum.Checked
            For S = 1 To intnum Step 1
                intsum = intsum + S
            Next




        End Select
    End If 
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value", "Input error")
    txtinput.Clear()
    txtinput.Focus()

End If
```